# VBA - thisworkbook.path

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code.

From a logical perspective, why is it not working (see below)? There is no error message.

Instead, when running the code, a folder opens where I can select manually the file and the tab.

When opening the file and the tab, the correct calculation is done.

However, I would like the macro to do exactly this for me :)

Example code:

```
*'define macro name*
Sub macro_additional_indicators()

Dim Path As String

*'define path variable = recent workbook folder*

Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

*'ignore this*

   Cells.Find(What:="Additional Indicators", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Select

*'here the thisworkbook.path command is used and*

    ActiveCell.Formula = "='Path & [COREP]C 02.00'!$E$19/1000000"

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

*'it should substitute the direct path stated here*

    ActiveCell.Formula = "='C:\Users\me\Desktop\KRI\[COREP]C 02.00'!$E$19/1000000"
```

Comment: `"='Path & [COREP]C 02.00'` should be `"='" & Path & "'[COREP]C 02.00'`

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift response Nathan. Applying your code leads to th error "400". Deleting the second ' in "='" & Path & "'[COREP]C 02.00' leads to a running code, but the calculation is not executed anymore. But I think I am a step closer towards the solution.

Comment: @Verena  I'm not sure of your problem. If the problem is that the formula in the cell does not contain the full path name, this information may be of value:  [Description of link management and storage in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328440/description-of-link-management-and-storage-in-excel)

Comment: @Ron: thanks as well! I think the issue is that excel does not take the value behind in the linked cell anymore and sees the first part until the [COREP] as a string. Thus the result is #REF. But of course there is also the likelihood that I am wrong :)

Comment: @Verena I thought you wrote that the calculation was correct.  You mentioned nothing about seeing an error value in the cell.  What, **exactly**, is the problem?

Comment: @Ron: Using my code leads to a correct end result, however, I have to select manually the file and the tab in the folder that pops up when running the code. The code from Nathan (minus the one ' in his code) does not lead to an open folder, however, the calculation (actually it is just a reference to a value in another spreadsheet divided by 1 mio) is not executed anymore. The result here is #REF!

Comment: @Verena The file dialog box opening means Excel is not seeing your pathname as a valid pathname; the `#REF!` when you correct the syntax means it sees it as a valid pathname, but there is no such existing object/sheet.  Suggest you do a `debug.print` on the entire string you are passing to the `Open`

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I think you are missing the file extension in your brackets
see how Excel refers to a file in my simple example I created by clicking the cells

```
='C:\Example\[Source.xlsx]Sheet1'!$F$7
```

So the enumaration here is: 
='Path[FilenameWithExtension]Sheetname'!CellAddress

So I can only guess it will be:

```
"='Path & [COREP.xlsm]C 02.00'!$E$19/1000000"
```

Or

```
"='Path & [COREP.xlsb]C 02.00'!$E$19/1000000"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your helpful comments! Call me crazy, but the solution of Nathan without the second ' works now. It first lead to #REF!, then I went for a coffee break and when I came back, closed everything and opened it again, it worked. Since I do not believe in magic I will investigate on this, however, issue solved. thanks!

The file extension is indeed not needed here, but I thought the same in the beginning :)